# Does every pole have non-zero residue?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, singularity

I am self-studying complex analysis.I am currently studying isolated singularity.There are $3$ kinds of singularities *viz.* removable singularity,pole and essential singularity.We know that if $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ then $f(z)=\frac{a_{-n}}{(z-z_0)^n}+\frac{a_{-(n-1)}}{(z-z_0)^{n-1}}+\dots+\frac{a_{-1}}{z-z_0}+H(z)$ where $H$ is a non vanishing holomorphic function in a neighborhood of $z_0$.$a_{-1}$ is called the residue of $f$ at $z_0$.My question is that can it happen that residue is $0$ but yet the function has a pole at $z_0$.I think the answer is yes,because we can take for example $f(z)=\frac{2}{z^2}+\sin(z)$ where $z\in \mathbb C-\{0\}$.Please tell me if I am correct.Also tell me what is the meaning of a zero residue?

Comment: Your example is correct, a simpler one is $f(z)=1/z^2$. It is allowed that $H$ is identically zero.

Comment: @MartinR If the pole is simple,then does zero residue imply that function has removable singularity?

Comment: This should help https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplePole.html If $(z-z_0)f(z)$ is analytic and the residue is zero, then $z_0$ is a removable singularity.

Comment: As Martin R already pointed out, $1/z^2$ has zero residue and $z=0$ is a true pole, not a removable singularity. The residue is the coefficient of $1/(z-z_0)$. A pole having residue $0$ just means that its $1/(z-z_0)$ term is missing. It is a pole of order $> 1$.